# Retrieve Missing relationship in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following **[schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e52f/3/0)**:

```
CREATE TABLE `filmati` (
  `idfilmato` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idfilmato`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `utenti` (
  `idutente` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idutente`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `utenti_has_filmati` (
  `fkutente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkfilmato` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fkutente`,`fkfilmato`),
  KEY `fk_Utenti_has_videos_videos1_idx` (`fkfilmato`),
  KEY `fk_Utenti_has_videos_Utenti_idx` (`fkutente`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Utenti_has_videos_Utenti` FOREIGN KEY (`fkutente`) REFERENCES `utenti` (`idutente`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Utenti_has_videos_videos1` FOREIGN KEY (`fkfilmato`) REFERENCES `filmati` (`idfilmato`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ;
```

And data:

```
Insert into filmati VALUES (1);
Insert into filmati VALUES (2);
Insert into filmati VALUES (3);

insert into utenti values(1);
insert into utenti values(2);
insert into utenti values(3);

insert into utenti_has_filmati values(1,2);
insert into utenti_has_filmati values(1,3);
insert into utenti_has_filmati values(2,3);
insert into utenti_has_filmati values(2,1);
insert into utenti_has_filmati values(3,1);
insert into utenti_has_filmati values(3,2);
```

I would like a query that can tell me the missing relationship

In this case:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(cross) join the two tables, so you get the combination of all filmati and all utenti (=cathesian product).

Then you can `left join` the junction table `utenti_has_filmati` to join all existing relations.

Then use the where clause to only return those records that have no matching row in the junction table

```
select u.idutente, f.idfilmato 
from 
  utenti u
  cross join filmati f
  left join utenti_has_filmati uf 
     on uf.fkutente = u.idutente and 
        uf.fkfilmato = f.idfilmato
where
  uf.fkfilmato is null -- Check for either field. Doesn't matter.
```

Comment: ty faster than Kàroly answer and some explain

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    A.idfilmato, B.idutente 
  FROM
    filmati A,utenti B
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM
      utenti_has_filmati AB
    WHERE
      AB.fkutente = A.idfilmato AND
      AB.fkfilmato = B.idutente
  )
```

Comment: Why use the old syntax? Why not `FROM filmati A  CROSS JOIN  utenti B`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, though semantically they are identical. I prefer using the comma syntax instead of the cross join to remind me that it must be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way is the following:

```
select idfilmato, idutente 
from filmati 
join utenti 
left outer join utenti_has_filmati on (idfilmato = fkfilmato and idutente = fkutente)
where fkutente is null;
```